# Add form field with AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

Here is the form:

```
function payment_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // since credit card is also an option, the gift card section is contained in this div.
  $form['payment']['giftcard'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
  );

  // there are additional fields above here, but trimmed them out since they are not relevant to the issue.
  $form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('giftcards'),
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="giftcards-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  // initialize the gift card field counter
  if (!isset($form_state['gift_cards'])) {
    $form_state['gift_cards'] = 1;
  }
  // build the fields
  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['gift_cards']; $i++) {
    $form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards']['gift_card_number'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Gift Card Number'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    );
  }
  // validate the current gift card and add another field.
  $form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards']['validate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Validate'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'validate_giftcard_add_field',
      'wrapper' => 'giftcards-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
    ),
  );
```

Here is the callback function for the AJAX call. There is no validation currently, just trying to get it to add another field. If I add print statements in this function they are being output in a javascript alert, so this function is being called. However it is not returning any new fields.

```
function validate_giftcard_add_field($form, $form_state) {
  $form_state['gift_cards']++;

  return $form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards'];
}
```

What is the right way to add new fields via ajax?

Additionally, all instances of  `'#required' => TRUE,` have been removed during my testing. I have not done anything with the validate or submit callbacks either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues here. The first was with the wrapper, changed the class to and id:

```
// there are additional fields above here, but trimmed them out since they are not relevant to the issue.
$form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('giftcards'),
  ),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="giftcards-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

The second issue is missing the submit callback for the ajax button:

```
// validate the current gift card and add another field.
$form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards']['validate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Validate'),
  '#submit' => array('validate_giftcard_add_field_submit'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'validate_giftcard_add_field',
    'wrapper' => 'giftcards-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);
```

Updated ajax callback:

```
function validate_giftcard_add_field($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['payment']['giftcard']['giftcards'];
}
```

Defined the ajax submit callback:

```
function validate_giftcard_add_field_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['gift_cards']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#ajax->wrapper` refers to an ID. Where as you have `class="giftcards-wrapper"`. Change it to ID and it should replace it.

Comment: This was only part of the issue, see my answer below.